# Is it possible to generate new parent element if there is no space for the dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, handlebars.js

**WHAT I ALREADY HAVE**

I am building "website" that looks like pdf.
Thanks to that I don't have any problem with styling when printing mode is ON.

For every page I use `<section class="page"></section>` which has parameters like width and height of the A4 format (in milimeters).

Some pages are static and some dynamic. When I have too much content on the page, `<section>` is extending it's height, but in printing mode it breaks to a new page what is fine enough, but it creates a few problems for me.

1. Footer with the page number (that is on every dynamic page) does not display correct number (it's generated on DOMcontentloaded via javascript, so it's not supposed to work when new page is generated in @media print)
2. On the last page footer is not at the bottom, but after last content. I fixed it by adding `position: fixed;` but then it is visible on EVERY page what is not I really want.

**WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE**

For now, it works like that:

```
<section class="page">
   <!-- LOOP: start -->
   <div class="box">
      <!-- dynamic content -->
   </div>
   <!-- LOOP: end -->

   <div class="footer"></div>
</section>
```

It would be perfect if I could do something like that:

```
<section class="page">
   <!-- LOOP: start -->
   <div class="box">
      <!-- dynamic content -->
     
      <!-- IF box can fit in this section, then generate it. ELSE create another section and 
      continue loop there -->
   </div>
   <!-- LOOP: end -->

   <div class="footer"></div>
</section>
```

So the result would be for example:

```
<section class="page">
   
   <div class="box">
      <!-- dynamic content -->
   </div>
   <div class="box">
      <!-- dynamic content -->
   </div>
   <div class="box">
      <!-- dynamic content -->
   </div>

   <div class="footer"></div>

</section>

<section class="page">
   
   <div class="box">
      <!-- dynamic content -->
   </div>
   <div class="box">
      <!-- dynamic content -->
   </div>
   <div class="box">
      <!-- dynamic content -->
   </div>

   <div class="footer"></div>

</section>

<section class="page">
   
   <div class="box">
      <!-- dynamic content -->
   </div>

   <div class="footer"></div>

</section>
```

In that case, my script to generate page numbers would work as expected and the footer would be always at the bottom.

Is is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. If I understood it correctly, I think setting an *absolute position* would work.

*fixed* position does what it says: it makes the element completely out of the screen flow and fixed on the screen. That's why it remains when your page moves.

You should try *position: absolute*
This makes the element positioned in reference to the nearest positioned parent.

So, you could set your <section> as *position: relative* (for example). This is needed so the *footer* child knows it should me positioned in reference to this parent element.

And then set your *footer* as position: absolute, also telling it to be positioned on the bottom of the parent element.

css:

```
.page {
  position: relative;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; // this means 0px from the bottom of the parent component
}
```

Comment: I see you are new here. If this answer satisfy your needs, please accept it as the correct one. :)

Comment: Unfortunately it won't help here. Here is why: if I set .page as relative then I can have only one footer at the bottom. As I said, I need footer on every page (I achieved that by putting it inside <tfoot> inside a table). However I need to create this footer in the normal view (not print mode) so I can modify page number

Comment: It would work if I find a solution to recreate .page when content can't fit into previous one

Comment: Oh... it seems that you talk about two different things when say "page"... one is the <section.page> and the other a pseudo-break included when on print view... is it the point?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for missunderstand :)

Comment: Ok, that’s more complicated. The only solution I can think of is to do it with JavaScript... like if <section.page> innerHeight is higher than the size of a A4, for example, to add dynamically to the dom a <div.page> node with a <div.footer>.